# Composer fails, package needs another package in require-dev

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, package

I am developing an application with Laravel 4 I have to develop a package for it, my package (let's call it xPAckage) needs this package vespakoen/menu, as you can see from its github 
https://github.com/vespakoen/menu
I have to add it to xPackage composer.json in

```
      require-dev
```

but the issue is this the by running the composer install application is not going to install the contents of require-dev of its packages it only installs the packages of

```
require part or require-dev
```

of its own.

And if I put that in the require part of the xPAckage, I will get the following error when running the composer update,

```
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
  imum-stability setting
```

how should I solve this issue?

**Edited : (on 23rd of Nov)**
The xPackage composer.json is like this:

```
{
"name": "packageName/xPcakge",
"description": "package description",
"keywords": ["xPAckage"],
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "user",
        "email": "email@domain.net"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "zofe/rapyd": "1.3.*",       
    "vespakoen/menu": "dev-master"   
},
   "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/controllers",
        "src/views",
        "src/models"
    ]
 }
}
```

And this is the composer.json file of the application,

```
 {
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
},
 "require-dev": {
    "packageName/xPcakge" : "dev-master"                   
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
 }
}
```

Comment: Post your `composer.json`.

Comment: @justinhoward I just edited the question could you please check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package `packageName/xPackage` requires `vespakoen/menu` by branch name (`dev-master`). When composer imports that package it treats it as if it had the `@dev` flag on it. So `packageName/xPackage` has a dependency with the stability level of `dev`. When composer tries to import `xPackage`, it loads all its dependencies as well. However, when it hits `vespakoen/menu`, it sees that it has a `dev` stability level. Your app, because it doesn't explicitly set a stability, has a level of `stable`. These two levels conflict. You can:

- Lower the stability level of your app to dev, **not recommended**.
  This will allow composer to install any dev level packages into your
  app. In your app's `composer.json`:

  ```json
  {
      "minimum-stability": "dev"
  }
  ```
- Use a stable version of `vespakoen/menu`. Go to the [packagist page](https://packagist.org/packages/vespakoen/menu) for it and choose a tagged version. This is the **preferred method**. In your package's `composer.json`:

  ```json
  {
      "require": {
          "vespakoen/menu": "~2.0"
      }
  }
  ```
- Require `vespakoen/menu` explicitly in your app. This will tell composer to override the default minimum-stability for this one case. In your app's `composer.json`:

  ```json
  {
      "require": {
          "vespakoen/menu": "dev-master"
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Don't require a FIXED version. Require a RANGE of versions. Preferred: `~2.0`, alternatively `2.0.*`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here and try some of the different versions:
https://packagist.org/packages/vespakoen/menu

Ex: "vespakoen/menu": "2.0.15"

Answer (score 1):

Never ever ever ever require branches! Always require versions, preferably version ranges for your dependencies.

Unfortunately a lot of install instructions took the simple route and suggest requiring "dev-master" as their version. This is wrong.

If the project announces to publish new versions according to semantic versioning, then require the minimum version that satisfies the features you need, with the tilde operator, like `~2.1`. This will tell that you need at least version 2.1.0, but anything better is fine as long as it does not introduce incompatible changes (that would be a new major number 3.0.0).

If the project does not announce anything like this, a version requirement of `2.1.*` may be correct if you have proof that the project broke "compatible" versions in the past and didn't correct this. This is less likely to be the case, and it is the more nasty variant, because you are forcing your own users to use a particular version of your dependency, without being able to freely upgrade that.